Theorem (13.20) Real and abstract analysis Stromberg
Theorem Let $p\in [1,\infty)$. For every $f\in L^p$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a simple function $\sigma\in L^p$ such that $\lvert \sigma \rvert\le \lvert f \rvert$ and $\lVert \sigma -f\rVert_p<\varepsilon$.
It's clear to me when $f\ge 0$. Let $f$ be arbitrary then $$f=(f_1-f_2)+i(f_3-f_4)$$ where $f_j$ are nonnegative, in detail $f_1=(\mathcal{R}(f))^+$, that is the positive part of the real part of $f$, $f_2=(\mathcal{R}(f))^-$, $f_3=(\mathcal{I}(f))^+$, and $f_4=(\mathcal{I}(f))^-$.  For all $\varepsilon>0$ we choose $\sigma_j$ such that $\sigma_j\le f_j$ and $\lVert \sigma_j - f_j \rVert_p<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$. Define $\sigma:=(\sigma_1-\sigma_2)+i(\sigma_3-\sigma_4)$. I do not understand why $$\lVert f -\sigma\rVert_p\le \sum_{j=1}^4\lVert f_j-\sigma_j \rVert_p$$
It is clear that $f_1f_2=f_3f_4=0$. We have that $0\le \sigma_j \le f_j$ for $j=1,\dots 4$
enter image description here
The first part of the proof is clear to me, Could someone explain the underlined passage to me? Thanks

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

It is just the triangle inequality. $$\|f-\sigma\|=\|(f_1-\sigma_1)+(-1)(f_2-\sigma_2)+(i)(f_3-\sigma_3)+(-i)(f_4-\sigma_4)\|\\\le\|f_1-\sigma_1\|+|(-1)|\|f_2-\sigma_2\|+|i|\|f_3-\sigma_3\|+|(-i)|\|f_4-\sigma_4\|\\=\sum_{j=1}^4\|f_j-\sigma_j\|$$
